# Popping item from .NET's Stack<T> class reduces memory usage?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, stack

Does popping an item from the .NET's `Stack<T>` reduce memory usage of that stack?

MSDN says that `Stack<T>` is implemented as an array so I guess that by popping an item only top element's pointer is moved to previous element, keeping all elements intact.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Wouldn't it be expensive to keep resizing the array every time you added/removed an element?

Comment: What happened when you actually removed items from the stack in your own application?  Did the memory usage go down, or not?

Comment: No, only TrimExcess() does this.  It has a good name.  Don't use it too often, it is expensive.

Comment: As far as I'm aware it won't be shrinked to a smaller size, it will only move the pointer back (at least that's what happens with List<T> without TrimExcess()). Would love to hear more, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at the source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,fd86d7436e55c84b,references

```
    // Pops an item from the top of the stack.  If the stack is empty, Pop
    // throws an InvalidOperationException.
    /// <include file='doc\Stack.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Stack.Pop"]/*' />
    public T Pop() {
        if (_size == 0)
            ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EmptyStack);
        _version++;
        T item = _array[--_size];
        _array[_size] = default(T);     // Free memory quicker.
        return item;
    }
```

It does not resize the array, but it does set that position in the array to `default` so, *if it's a reference type*, garbage collection will clean up the object that used to be there, and thus free up memory. If it's a value type, it won't make a difference.

Comment: Where do you see the array being resized?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's not actually resized. Just the value of `_size` is changed.

Comment: It's probably more "correct" to say that the item that was previously in the last position of the array will get collected (eventually). The value itself doesn't get set to `default`, rather the last (usable) element of the array does.

Answer (score 0):

No, the memory usage of the stack will remain the same. However if `T` is a reference type and the popped element has no other live reference then it could eventually be collected by the GC and the memory of the popped instance would be reclaimed, but this won't affect in any way the memory usage of the stack per se.

If `T` is a value type then it doesn't make a difference at all, because any given `T` or `default(T)` will have the same memory footprint.